# How to Select if div has class in component side on Angular

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular, How to check if particular div has a some class like jquery and update the that div class,

In jquery i know how to do, But in angular how to do,

```
$("#sidebarToggle").on('click',function(e) {
    $(".sidebar").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

I have tried below code in angular 5.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  toggleclass= '';

  public open() {
    this.toggleclass= 'toggled';  
  }
}
```

In Html

```
<button id="sidebarToggle" (click)="open()">Toggle</button>
<ul class="sidebar navbar-nav {{toggleclass}}"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `class.className` to conditionally add a class to an HTML Element in your DOM.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {

  classToggled = false;

  public toggleField() {
    this.classToggled = !this.classToggled;  
  }
}
```

And in your Template:

```
<button 
  id="sidebarToggle" 
  (click)="toggleField()">Toggle</button>

<ul 
  class="sidebar navbar-nav"
  [class.toggled]="classToggled">
</ul>
```

`toggled` here is the name of class that you'd like to apply on the `div`.

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditionally-toggle-class-on-button-click?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Yes but when i click button again i have to remove the class of sidebar ul

Comment: @spsaravananct, I've updated my answer.. I've also added a Working Sample StackBlitz for your ref.

Comment: Hi one more thing @Sidd How can we access index.html from app component

Comment: @spsaravananct, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want toggle body class also that is index.html only.